# I can log into my AWS/EC2 instance but my developer can't

Tags: ssh, aws-ec2

I created a new EC2 instance, generated a key with PuTTYgen and was able to successfully log in on my machine using Pageant and PuTTY as well as WinSCP. My security group is open to all IPs, but my developer in another state (I'm in the US) is unable to replicate this same log in procedure, even after remoting into my machine to see exactly how I accessed the server. He gets a permission denied error. Any ideas why?

Comment: Read the sshd logs on the server.

Comment: Without actual error message you get this is not answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. It looks like his version of PuTTY was outdated. He updated and it worked.